# How to count specific char in vba

Tags: vba, excel

So I need to count how many ž and č are there in all of these fields.
Example.
http://prntscr.com/jwz1em

I tryed with this code but it gives me 0

```
Function slova(iVal)
Dim output As Integer
output = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2:A11"), "ž")
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see multiple problems with your code:

- There is no assignment of return value to function, in my example `slova = charCnt`, so it wouldn't return anything besides default 0 no matter what.
- It lacks `Application.Volatile`, so the formula used in Excel cell would require navigating to cell and pressing ENTER to force an update when data in range changes.
- Function has an argument `iVal` which isn't used anywhere.
- `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf` returns count of cells, so it is limited to 1 character per cell. On top of it, correctly specified argument would be `"*ž*"`

Here is my solution to count all occurrences of hardcoded character in hardcoded range (must have exactly 1 column).

```
Function slova() As Long

    Application.Volatile

    Dim vData As Variant
    Dim rowCounter As Long, charCnt As Long
    Const myLetter As String = "ž"

    vData = Range("A2:A11")

    For rowCounter = LBound(vData) To UBound(vData)
        If vData(rowCounter, 1) <> vbNullString Then
            charCnt = charCnt + UBound(Split(vData(rowCounter, 1), myLetter))
        End If
    Next rowCounter

    slova = charCnt

End Function
```

As you use function, you can also take advantage of it and use source range as an argument, the same goes for character.

Comment: thank you alot, this works exactly as I needed it :)

Comment: Do not use `Application.Volatile` unless absolutely needed. `Application.Volatile` is only useful for UDF.